# Is there any abstraction in .NET that encapsulates MethodInfo + instance?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm playing with Reflection and I would like to encapsulate a call to an instance method.

I always end up doing something like this:

```
methodInfo.Invoke(instance, parameters)
```

I wonder if there's any way to encapsulate it to something like `call.Invoke(parameters)`, where the instance is implicit.

Comment: Are you looking for something in the System library, or do you just want to write something for yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a delegate that binds the instance.
You can do this either with the static `Delegate.CreateInstance` method or with the `MethodInfo.CrateInstance` method.  The former relies on you knowing that the instance is actually a hidden first parameter to the method, so the latter may be a little more clear.

```cs
    class Thing
    {
        int _Number;
        public Thing(int number) { _Number = number; }
        public int GetNumber() { return _Number; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Thing thingOne = new Thing(1);
        Thing thingTwo = new Thing(2);

        MethodInfo getter = typeof(Thing).GetMethod("GetNumber");
        Func<int> getOne = (Func<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>), thingOne, getter);
        Func<int> getTwo = (Func<int>)getter.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>), thingTwo);

        Console.WriteLine(getOne());
        Console.WriteLine(getTwo());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply this:

```
public class MethodInvoker
{
    private MethodInfo _method;
    private object _target;

    public MethodInvoker(MethodInfo method, object target)
    {
        _method = method;
        _target = target;
    }

    public object Invoke(params object[] parameters) => _method.Invoke(_target, parameters);
}

...


string s = "Hello";

var invoker = new MethodInvoker(s.GetType().GetMethod("Substring",new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }), s);

Console.WriteLine(invoker.Invoke(1,3));
```

You might use generics for type safety on the target or return type.